# Failed to build iOS app Error output from Xcode build , for flutter

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, visual-studio, dart

after deleting firebase files and disconnecting it from my project I can't connect to the Xcode simulator anymore to run my project
what's the problem
tried too many ways to fix it but it didn't work

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 13 in debug mode...
lib/main.dart:1
Xcode build done.                                            2.0s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    2022-10-07 22:10:41.596 xcodebuild[4518:45824] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.IDEKit.ExtensionSentinelHostApplications for extension Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.AppExtensionHosts.watchOS of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportCore
    2022-10-07 22:10:41.596 xcodebuild[4518:45824] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.IDEKit.ExtensionPointIdentifierToBundleIdentifier for extension Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.AppExtensionToBundleIdentifierMap.watchOS of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportCore
    ** BUILD FAILED **
Xcode's output:
↳
    Writing result bundle at path:
        /var/folders/ty/kz1w949118g4t4srbr_fdr_00000gn/T/flutter_tools.vp3VZA/flutter_ios_build_temp_dirSoQ62R/temporary_xcresult_bundle
    note: Using new build system
    note: Planning
    note: Build preparation complete
    warning: Building targets in manual order is deprecated - check "Parallelize build for command-line builds" in the project editor, or set DISABLE_MANUAL_TARGET_ORDER_BUILD_WARNING in any of the targets in the current build to suppress this warning
    error: Unexpected duplicate tasks
2
        note: Target 'Runner' (project 'Runner') has copy command from '/Users/koc/Desktop/development/flutterplayground/secondapp/ios/Runner/GoogleService-Info.plist' to '/Users/koc/Desktop/development/flutterplayground/secondapp/ios/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/GoogleService-Info.plist'
    warning: ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=YES requested with multiple ARCHS and no active architecture could be computed; building for all applicable architectures (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
    Result bundle written to path:
        /var/folders/ty/kz1w949118g4t4srbr_fdr_00000gn/T/flutter_tools.vp3VZA/flutter_ios_build_temp_dirSoQ62R/temporary_xcresult_bundle
Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 13.
Exited
```

Comment: please provide your main.dart code i believe you have to remove the Firebase initialisation.

Comment: I removed it already from main and from yaml

Comment: i have an idea but first did you remove the googleService-info.plist ?

Answer (score 0):

Reading your log this line got my attention :

```
ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=YES requested with multiple ARCHS and no active architecture could be computed
```

click on your target > build settings > VALID_ARCHS > and add the following :

```
arm64 arm64e armv7 armv7s x86_64
```

[image]

in case you didn't find the `VALID_ARCHS` do the following:

1- Click on the plus sign under the Build Settings.

2- Choose "Add user-defined settings" and it will add NEW_SETTING to you.

3- Rename the "NEW_SETTING" to "VALID_ARCHS" and add the following builds:

```
arm64 arm64e armv7 armv7s x86_64
```